# Unable to read each word in a text file

Tags: c++, xcode

I have got a text file with contents:

> Artificial neural networks (ANNs) or connectionist systems are
>   computing systems vaguely inspired by the biological neural networks
>   that constitute animal brains.[1] Such systems "learn" (i.e.
>   progressively improve performance on) tasks by considering examples,
>   generally without task-specific programming. For example, in image
>   recognition, they might learn to identify images that contain cats by
>   analyzing example images that have been manually labeled as "cat" or
>   "no cat" and using the results to identify cats in other images. They
>   do this without any a priori knowledge about cats, e.g., that they
>   have fur, tails, whiskers and cat-like faces. Instead, they evolve
>   their own set of relevant characteristics from the learning material
>   that they process.

and I'm using this code to read the contents.

```
ifstream file("/Users/sourav/Desktop/stl/stl/stl/testdata.txt");
while (! file.eof()) {
    string word;
    file >> word ;
    cout << word << "\n";
}
```

This is the first few lines of output:

```
Artificial

neural

(ANNs)

are

vaguely
```

and if you notice that the contents are not read properly. I don't see `or connectionist systems  are computing systems`.

I'm **missing** few string values from the text file while reading it.

Note:I'm using Xcode.

```
ifstream file("/Users/sourav/Desktop/stl/stl/stl/dictionary.txt");
string line;

if (file.is_open())  // same as: if (myfile.good())
{

    while(getline(file,line,'\r')){
         transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), ::tolower);
        Dictionary.insert(line);


    }
    cout<<Dictionary.size()<<" words read from dictionary\n";
    file.close();
```

Why does the dictionary.size() change in value when I transform it to lowercase

Comment: The concerns belo about about `while (! file.eof())` are valid. [It's a common bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong), but I can't see how this results in the problem you are reporting. [Bashing out a quick test case](https://ideone.com/GyMKyD), I'm unable to reproduce.  Obviously the linked code cannot run, no file, but it does expose one of the many problems with `while (! file.eof())`: If the file did not open it will never hit EOF. Please add a [mcve] to the question so we can see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not explain why it does not work, your code may look like:

```
ifstream file("testdata.txt");
do {
  string word;
  file >> word ;
  if (!file.good()) break;
  cout << word << "\n";
} while (!file.eof());
```

It is not correct to test for `eof` condition if you never tried to read something first.

This code (and yours while being logically incorrect) works perfectly. So something else is happening (that is not related to `xcode`).

Answer (score 1):

Try using something along the lines of this:

```
ifstream file("/Users/sourav/Desktop/stl/stl/stl/testdata.txt");

string word;
while(file >> word) //While there is a word to get... get it and put it in word
{
    cout << word <<"\n";
}
```

A little bit more of an explanation can be found on the accepted answer in question [read word by word from file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372661/read-word-by-word-from-file-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I don't see much of a difference in logic though between this and your logic.

Comment: Still the same results

Comment: This answer should work. Whatever is causing failure is elsewhere.