# How to read all strings from a file - C++

Tags: string

I try to read all the strings from the file "Text.txt" and add the strings to a vector by using this code:

```
std::ifstream in;
in.open("Text.txt");
std::vector<std::string> vec;
while (!in.eof()) {
  in >> str;
  vec.push_back(str);
}
```

The problem is that I read the last string twice.
Any idea why this is happening?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read word by word from file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372661/read-word-by-word-from-file-in-c)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer my problem. I am aware of this solution, but I cannot use it because of some specifics of my problem.

Comment: Care to be more specific?  It literally explains your exact problem in all the detail you've provided.  tldr: Don't use `.eof()`  use `while(in >> str)`.  What is different about the specifics of your problem?  Please divulge the details.

Comment: Thank you Wick, I finally solved my problem by using while(in >>str). Still, I don't understand the behavior when using while (!in.eof()), why is the last string read twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained [elsewhere on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20372777/1563833) already.

In this order:

1. `in.eof()` checks `eofbit` which is false.  No read operation has read the end of file yet.  The loop continues.
2. `in >> str` encounters the end of file and sets `eofbit`. This also leaves `str` unchanged from the last iteration,
3. you push the old (unchanged) `str` which is now in your vector twice,
4. you exit the loop when `in.eof()` checks `eofbit`.

Your misunderstanding is that `in.eof`is doing something to detect the
end of file condition -- **but, it's not**. It just checks `eofbit`.
`eofbit` isn't set until the `>>` operation is performed.

Carefully read documentation for [ios::eof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/), which I shall excerpt here:

> `std::ios::eof`
>
> Returns true if the `eofbit` *error state flag* is set for the stream.
>
> This flag is set by all standard input operations when the End-of-File
> is reached in the sequence associated with the stream.
>
> Note that the value returned by this function depends on the last
> operation performed on the stream (and not on the next).

#### To fix the problem

`in >> str` will return whether or not a string was read.  Just base your loop condition on that.

```
while(in >> str)
   vec.push_back(str);
```